# jquery autocomplete and datepicker compatability issue?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, zend-form, uidatepicker, jquery-autocomplete

I have a form that is constructed using ZendX_JQuery_Form, the form contains 2 auto complete inputs and 4 datepickers. The datepickers all worked absolutely fine until I added in the autocomplete fields as well, the autocomplete fields (linking to a backend php action in zend framework) work fine as well but they seem to break the datepicker widgets.

I know very little about JQuery but the javascript that ZF creates seems okay to me:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#firstname").autocomplete({"url":"crm\/candidates\/searchfirstname"});
        $("#lastname").autocomplete({"url":"crm\/candidates\/searchlastname"});
        $("#registeredfrom").datepicker({});
        $("#registeredto").datepicker({});
        $("#updatedfrom").datepicker({});
        $("#updatedto").datepicker({});
 });
```

Does anyone know of any issues in either JQuery or Zend Framework that or with the code above that might cause this scenario. Also, it would be helpful even if you know there are no issues in either of the frameworks to help me narrow down the search!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Caused by the autocomplete code not being included in the 1.7.2 jquery release, downloaded the autocomplete.js 1.3.2 release and included it in the zend view and it works absolutely fine.

Comment: Good that you have found the answer yourself. Could you mark the question as answered?